# Test of proportions when sample size is not known

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I want to compare two proportions, say $p_1$ and $p_2$. I want to test the null that $\pi_1 = \pi_2$ where $\pi_i$ is the true unknown proportion for sample $i$. The problem is that I do not know the sample size which underlies the calculation of $p_2$ and hence cannot use the standard two-sample, independent proportion test.

Can I, instead, assume that $p_2$ is a fixed value and then perform a standard one-sample, proportion test? Is there a better approach?

Comment: So, for $p_2$ someone just handed you a number, is that correct? What do you have for $p_1$, a vector of $1$s & $0$s?

Comment: @gung It is a bit complex. $p_2$ is the overall average of several studies each one of which has its own sample size. All I know is that the sample size of each one of these individual studies is probably very high (maybe in the range of a 1000 to, not sure about this). $p_1$ is a vector of $1$s and $0$s.

Comment: Do you know the component proportions (ie, from the individual studies) that went into $p_2$? Most likely, $p_2$ should be a *weighted* average of those proportions, where the individual study sample sizes are the weights, not the *simple* average. Note that this fact adds additional complexity to @Glen_b's otherwise good answer below.

Comment: Perhaps, it is weighted avg. I do not have access to that information. And, no I do not know the component proportions.

Comment: But you have good reason to believe that *every one* of those sample proportions is based on $N>1k$, & that all the proportions from the prior studies are sufficiently equivalent?

Comment: @gung Actually, if they use weighted proportions (and don't round off prematurely), then we're actually back to a simple ratio of integers and my suggested bound on $n$. If they use an unweighted average, it's a bit trickier, since the smallest component $n_i$ may have a relatively big effect on the standard error of the average, but we may still be able to get some sort of usable bound on the s.e. of $p_2$. The more we know about how $p_2$ was obtained, the better the chances of making an argument about its size.

Comment: I agree w/ you there, @Glen_b. What I'm wondering is whether the whole endeavor makes sense. Imagine $p_2=.5$, but this is based on the averages from 2 studies where $p=.25$ & $p=.75$, respectively, w/ $N=1k$ in both cases.

Comment: prop, can you get *even one* of the component study values?

Comment: @gung Good question regarding equivalency. I do not think we can assume that the component proportions all have the same true proportion. So, in some sense, I want to test if the proportion I have is significantly different from the overall 'average' proportion. For example, think of $p_1$ as percentage of people who would vote Clinton in NH whereas $p_2$ is the 'average' percentage of people who would vote for Clinton in the remaining 49 states. This discussion with you and Glen has been very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @gung for a proportions test to make sense any time, you have to assume homogeneity; if that's not reasonable, then even if you can justify the comparison (what's the population about which your inference is being made?), you have bigger issues - like computing a bound on your standard error.

Comment: Do you know how many components are in the average for $p_2$? If you do this number could be used as a lower bound for the sample size.

Comment: prop in what sense does an average of different proportions represent any population value at all? Sampled in different ratios, you get a different average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uncertainty in $p_2$ may be very large, so no.

Imagine $p_2 = 0.67$.

Now that could be 67 out of 100, in which case the standard error of that estimate of $\pi_2$ is about 0.047, so $\pi_2$ might be 0.6 or 0.75 ... but probably won't be 0.5 or 0.95.

However, that $p_2$ might also be 2 out of 3, rounded off - and in the latter case, a very wide range of population proportions could reasonably have given 2 successes out of 3. Assuming $p_2$ is exactly $\pi_2$ would be silly.

*But all is not lost.*

There's another possibility.

Depending on its value it might be possible to put a lower bound on the $n$ and make progress that way. For example, if $p_2 = 0.412$, the smallest $n$ consistent with that is 17 (7/17 = 0.4117, rounded to 0.412) - no smaller sample size can produce 0.412 with rounding (whether off, up or down).

If you assume the $n$ is at least as large as the smallest $n$ that could have produced your sample proportion, then you will get an upper bound on the p-value. If you're lucky the smallest $n$ consistent with your proportion won't be something like 5.

The more significant figures you have for $p_2$, the better your chances of a useable lower bound on $n$. But if it's a value like 0.67... well, you better hope $p_1$ is a loong way away from it.

Comment: Actually, the sample size is probably very high (maybe, in the thousands) which would justify taking $p_2$ as a fixed value, no?

Comment: It's not me you have to convince that it's justifiable. Do you have some way of putting a lower limit on how big it might be? Some real evidence that it's large? If you just say "it's probably really big", a journal editor or a referee are both likely to check whether the calendar says April 1. Who do you need to convince and what do you have to convince them with? How certain can you be that it *isn't* small?

Comment: Well, first I need to convince myself that I am not doing something shaky and your answer helps in understanding the role sample size plays. Unfortunately, no precise lower limit is available.

Comment: If you can convincingly argue "it's at least 100", then you can simply take $n=100$; unless your $p_2$ is quite close to 0 or 1 *and* your $p$-value is close to your significance level, if you reject at some $n$, you'll reject at greater $n$.

Comment: If you can't make such an argument, the discussion that it's probably quite large (and what that might mean for a test) would come after you discuss what you can confidently show.

Comment: prop I see I missed some detail in your discussion with gung. Such information (several studies, probably fairly large $n$ in each) really should go in your question. Does whoever the source of $p_2$ is have further information on either the $n$'s (even one or two may help) or the individual $p$'s, or how they were combined? DO you at least know how many studies?